# Azure: Activating AGIC for existing Application Gateway via Terraform does not work completely

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

if I activate AGIC for AKS via Terraform for an existing Application Gateway:

```
  addon_profile {
    ingress_application_gateway {
      enabled    = true
      gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.application-gateway-network-1.id
    }
  }
```

and I deploy a hello-world ingress-application the rules etc. within the existing Application Gateway are not automatically created. If I change nothing but disabling AGIC via Azure Portal and enable it again: all works fine! Rules/health probes etc. are created automatically if I deploy the same hello-world ingress-application.
It seems to be a bug on Terraform or Azure API side but cannot find anything. maybe someone as a hint or even a solution?

I tried it with different AKS versions and use the latest Terraform Azurem provider 2.98.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also tried with Terraform Azurem provider 2.99

Comment: Also tried with Terraform Azurem provider 3.3.0

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Currently having the same issue but I'm not using addon_profile as it doesn't seem to exist in >= 3.3.0 https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.3.0/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster

Comment: I'm also struggling with this when describing the application gateway inside of the aks resource, it seems to re-write the entire application gateway to its defaults, almost like its creating a new one. 

I think this is because the gateway_id parameter creates a new gateway with that ID instead of checking to see if one already exists and uses that.

Answer (score 2):

Using azurerm provider `>=3.0.0` you'll need to move the `ingress_application_gateway` outside of the `addon_profile` as that's no longer supported.

Passing the `gateway_name` and a `subnet_cidr` instead of the `gateway_id` works for me, as Azure create ingress and assigns to the k8s cluster. This saves the need to create an `azurerm_application_gateway` resource.

Use the following.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-cluster" {
    ingress_application_gateway {
      gateway_name = "aks-cluster-ingress"
      subnet_cidr = "10.225.0.0/16"
    }
}
```

*Note: change the gateway_name and subnet_cidr values accordingly.*

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I want to use an existing application gateway because I want to configure this gateway via terraform (firewall policy rules, WAF_v2 etc). There were (IMHO) 2 other possibilities for me: 1. Activate the ingress controller via "az cli" (also in Terraform as shell command)  2. (Like you) create a new  application gateway via "ingress_application_gateway" and import the state in Terraform to be able to configure the application gateway. I am not really sure which way to go.

Comment: No worries, thank makes sense. Do you terraform your app gateway as well? If so, happy to take a look at that.